# While retrieving or deploying Data using Ant Migration tool Error As java.io.IOException: Access is denied

Tags: deployment, ant, migration-tool

I am unable to retrieve Code Using Ant Migration Tool. By using Command: 
ant retrieve code, Gettig an Error As **java.io.IOException: Access is denied**.

Attaching CMD Error Screen.`

```
C:\Program Files\apache-ant-1.10.5\sample>ant retrieveCode
Buildfile: C:\Program Files\apache-ant-1.10.5\sample\build.xml

retrieveCode:
[sf:retrieve] Request for a retrieve submitted successfully.
[sf:retrieve] Request ID for the current retrieve task: 09S6F000004hRc1UAE
[sf:retrieve] Waiting for server to finish processing the request...
[sf:retrieve] Request Status: Succeeded

BUILD FAILED
C:\Program Files\apache-ant-1.10.5\sample\build.xml:30: java.io.IOException: Access is denied
        at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
        at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1012)
        at com.salesforce.ant.ZipUtil.unzip(ZipUtil.java:72)
        at com.salesforce.ant.RetrieveTask.handleResponse(RetrieveTask.java:140)
        at com.salesforce.ant.SFDCMDAPIAntTaskRunner.runTask(SFDCMDAPIAntTaskRunner.java:92)
        at com.salesforce.ant.RetrieveTask.execute(RetrieveTask.java:110)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:99)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:350)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:449)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:470)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1388)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1361)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:834)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:223)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:284)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:101)

Total time: 12 seconds`
```

Comment: Are you using system -admin cred? Also the machine you are using ant, do you have write access to that folder?

Comment: Yes, I am using System Admin Creds only and I am also having access to that folder also.

Comment: What is written in build.xml line 30? this is the line that fails. Maybe it is a problem with writing to your local hard drive?

Comment: How to overcome this  Error @ Itai Shmida

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the problem above is due to saving Ant exe file in local Drive C and executing it.due to that it is unable to access build file during reterving code process, the best practice is to avoid using ant or tool in another local drive instead of C drives..